# Trouble getting PHPUnit code coverage command working

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm relearning PHPUnit, and I found the code-coverage command `./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage`. When I do it, I get the `No whitelist configured` error, which I'm led to believe is also the error you get when your whitelist isn't setup properly, but I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">/src/*</directory>
            <!--<file>/path/to/file</file>-->
            <exclude>
                <!--<directory suffix=".php">/path/to/files</directory>-->
                <!--<file>/sr</file>-->
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: why do you have the comments in the `exclude` section?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the format from a good, didn't need those parts and just commented them out while I tried to get it to work. The comments would be deleted before any commits. Is still valid XML so I didn't think it matters.

Comment: It matters I suppose, try to delete all the node out

Comment: Tried it out; there's no difference in behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take in mind that paths are relative to phpunit.xml config file. Maybe

```
<directory suffix=".php">/src/*</directory>
```

should be

```
<directory suffix=".php">src/*</directory>
```

if phpunit.xml is on project root folder

Comment: I didn't even notice I did that! Thanks for the catch and explanation.